# How to have desktop icons constantly highlighted?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows 7 when I set the desktop color, it actually sets the color of text in desktop icons. So if I have a black wallpaper, I need to set it to white so icon text will be visible.

If I want to have a multi-colored wallpaper then this causes a problem, as icon text won't be readable over areas where color is the same as the set desktop color.

Is there a way to have icons constantly highlighted to avoid this?

Comment: You can change the the windows theme colours indepentantly by right clicking the desktop, select personalize > window colour > advanced setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some links that have lots of information about the solution of your problem..

check these links [Link1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-you-change-icon-text-color-in-windows-7/b913c2c8-133c-4308-9987-47e6759f5c20) [LInk2](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=18279) [Link3](http://www.mydigitallife.info/fix-transparent-or-invisible-desktop-icon-text-after-installing-dreamscene-in-windows-7/)

there some solutions like:
Go to `Control Panel>System>Advanced`, and click Settings in the Performance section. Turn on the '`Use drop shadows for icon labels`' on the desktop option, and click Ok.

Hope these help you to solve problem..

Comment: I already had drop shadows enabled and am having the problem though.

Comment: it is just a example .. those link  i have specified those have some other tricks and way to solve the problem.. not just use drop shadow only...

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of work, and relies on you having a static background (i.e. not a slideshow) and keeping your icons in the same place all the time, but you could take your desktop background into a picture editor which supports layers (Photoshop, Paint.NET ...) and draw filled rectangles under the icon text locations.

As a rough step-by step:

```
1. Print screen your desktop
2. Paste into picture editor
3. Add new layer
4. Draw filled rectangles over all icon texts
5. Take the ORIGINAL WALLPAPER PICTURE (no icons) and paste
   it on top of the desktop screenshot
6. Save the file, and use as desktop background
```